# Stylistic question

Tags: gm.general-mathematics, mathematical-writing

I'm writing up a paper now where I'm the only author and have a stylistic question.

Should I write ''I'' or ''we'' as in ''I/we recall the definition...'' etc. I think this simple example will make everyone understand what I'm talking about.

Or should/can I mix? Is this too confusing. Or simply bad? Or ok?

I feel that ''we'' is maybe a bit too formal and ''I'' gives the paper a certain personal cosy touch. But in certain respects ''we'' is more ''we go through this ordeal together you and I, dear reader'', where ordeal can mean anything in a whole spectrum of things. You know what I'm saying.

So?

Comment: If you have plans on publishing the paper somewhere, then why not look at the places you're thinking of, see what people do there, and do the same? 

When I was writing my thesis, I noticed that everyone seemed to use "we" in e.g. the Inventiones papers I was using for references, so I used "we". 

On the other hand if you're thinking of sending the paper to some more informal journal then you might want to use a more informal style.

Comment: Oh, I have plans to send it somewhere, I just haven't decided where yet. In any case it seems that there is some kind of consensus in writing math papers that one should use ''we''. I'm just asking if I should start a revolution :)

Comment: Oh, lots of people use "I" already. It's a matter of taste; I'm not all that fond of it, because it feels like it directs too much attention to the author's performance. (I also like the gloss you put on "we"; it's really the right way to think of it.) 


Comment: Good point, Todd. Haven't thought of that implication. It *does* drag the author's ego to a rather inappropriate focal point, doesn't it?  

Comment: Suppose there is a rule against starting a sentence with a symbol.  Then, when your symbol is the subject of the sentence, you add a little meaningless something to start.  There are many somethings to choose from.  One is "We have...".  But I do not recall ever seeing it as "I have...".

Comment: Halmos, writing about mathematics writing, said he prefers "we", but thinks of it as meaning "the author and the reader".  But then he remarks not to use it when it really does mean just the author, and quotes one paper as saying: "We wish to thank our wife..."

Comment: What Gerald Edgar said. "We" = "author and the reader", but "I" = "author". Thus "I learned this argument from x", but "we will consider such examples below...". Many people use this rule. As far as I'm concerned, it's the perfect solution.

Comment: Rules are made to be broken. But they're only worth breaking if the payoff is worth it. So ask yourself: "Is there anything in this paper that justifies attracting extra attention to the form at the expense of contents?" And by the way, you would not be starting a revolution. There are many math papers that are written in an idiosyncratic style; I am not aware that they ever spawned imitators. A favorite example of such idiosyncratic writing must be Abhyankar's Historical Ramblings in Algebraic Geometry and Related Algebra
http://mathdl.maa.org/mathDL/22/?pa=content&sa=viewDocument&nodeId=2964

Comment: Well, we don't have strong feelings about the issue. 
Another option
is to side step this, by replacing "We denote the real numbers by
$\mathbb{R}$." with "The real numbers are denoted by $\mathbb{R}$"
etc. However, this commenter would not suggest that this always
a good idea.

Comment: @Donu, wouldn't the rule of replacement suggested by your final sentence be the somewhat pretentious "The author denotes the real numbers by $\mathbb{R}$?". Or, perhaps your final sentence should have been "However, this replacement is considered to not always be a good idea."

Comment: Willie, I agree. Third person almost always looks bizarre.

Comment: In cases such as this, the pronoun is not needed at all: "Recall the definition...", "Denote by $V$ a vector space...", etc. are OK, functioning grammatically as an imperative, which can be read as applying either to the reader or to both author and reader (in which case it's short for "Let us recall/denote ...").

Comment: Ok, this seems be getting a little out of hand with all commenting and no answers. I think it could be argued that I got sort of a consensus of what is appropriate. So let's leave this question and go on with our lives :) I suggest we close it now, unless some extremely interesting answer comes up soon. 

Comment: (Forgot to mention: this imperative construction is perhaps most familiar in the context of "Let $X$ be ...", which feels much more common than "We let $X$ be ...", let alone "I let $X$ be ...".) 

Comment: Another possibility: follow the lead from French and say things like "one can check" or "one sees that..."

Comment: Some say "rules are made to be broken".  I like Paul Halmos' way of putting that: Don't break the rules until after you know what they are.

Comment: The one person I read who regularly used "I" is George Leo Watson, who was largely self-educated, then retained a conversational style of writing after becoming part of the mainstream: 

http://www.numbertheory.org/obituaries/OTHERS/watson.html 



Comment: The place where "I" seems most appropriate is when one says "I am not aware of..." or "I do not know how to prove.."; indeed, the reader/audience might know, so "we" sounds silly or arrogant. Some people manage to avoid "I" using "this author" instead. This commenter prefers "I".

Comment: I was once quite confused by a statement in a paper, like *I can frequently vanish*, or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interest of having an answer and since this is CW anyway:

English is not my native language and (thus) I read several articles/books/chapeters on mathematical writing in English, among others by Halmos, Krantz, and Knuth (et al.)

I do not have the references handy and, since it's been a while, do not recall what precisely they said (and in particular not who said what exactly), but the consesus is definitely 'we' (with exceptions for things like thanks and so on; or, somebody said roughly: one of the rare situations where 'I' feels appropriate is to say 'I could not prove this conjecture' where both 'we' and 'one' seem odd; and also for the 'thanks')

So, I strongly recommend using 'we', in the sense you mentioned yourself (the author and the reader) and using 'I' only if it is a really somehow personal statement.

There is the additional question of using 'the author' instead of 'I' (in the above exceptional cases). Here, I think the situation is slightly less clear. Typically, if I am the sole author I write 'I' as writing myself 'the author' feels somehow strange for me. But, I had at least once a journal that changed this (in the Acknowledgment something like 'I thank..' was change to 'The author thanks...').

In case of multiple authors I am a bit more likely to write 'the authors' (in the exceptional cases) in order not to have two different 'we' (authors and reader as well as just the authors).

Personally, I think an additional advantage of the 'we' (instead of 'I') is that thus articles are written in the same way no matter whether it is single authored or coauthored.
To have single authored ones with 'I' and coauthored ones with 'we' seems confusing (well, maybe confusing is a too strong word, but I'd find it at least mildly distracting).

And, finally, how incovenient would it be, one starts a project alone and starts to write a bit of it up, and latter one finds a coauthor...then one would have to change all the 'I' to 'we'.